# Map custom domain with AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, subdomain, aws-amplify, amazon-route53

I have purchased one domain from google Domain. i.e. punjabaap.com . I successfully map my root domain with my amplify app. But I have one more app for testing purpose, now I need to map the domain with my testing app i.e. staging.punjabaap.com . But when I try to map it it stuck on configuration part. Even I have added my all CNAME in my google domain DSN. Can any one guide me why it is happening.

[image]